# What is the difference between -ic and -al?

Tags: ic-ical

Is there a defined difference between words like "egotistic" and egotistical" or "manic" and "maniacal" in that one could have a manic smile or maniacal laughter and other words that have similar forms?

Comment: @tchrist Because I didn't check to see if it was a duplicate, because it pleases me, because what's it to you.

Comment: @deadrat What’s it to me is that I am trying to make the site better. It is a disservice to future visitors to answer duplicates because unless they’re registered (and 90% are not), **they will never see your answer** because of the way redirects work, and so it comes off as the cheap reputation ploy that I would like to think it is not.

Comment: @tchrist Good idea.

Comment: @tchrist I'm sorry my comment appeared in the wrong place.  That said, if 90% of future visitors will never see my answer, then it can hardly be a disservice to them, now can it?  You wanna make this cite better?  Then how about you err on the side of politeness and respect?  I'll be happy to write a replacement for the question that treats me as an errant schoolboy caught caught defacing the walls in the loo.  Just let me know.

Comment: @tchrist  And you "would like to think" that I'm not a cheap rep whore, but you just can't quite bring yourself to believe it, eh?  Well played.

Comment: @deadrat If you truly wish to help, then please delete your answer and move it where it belongs. Thank you for your help in making the site better.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you for redirecting my question. I did not realize it was a duplicate but the other question works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* notes that

> [o]ften ... the form in *ic* is restricted to the sense of 'of' or 'of
>   the nature of' the subject in question, while that in *-ical* has
>   wider or more transferred senses including that of 'practically
>   connected' or 'dealing with' the subject.

The editors ask us to compare "'*economic* science'" and "'an *economical* wife'".

> But in many cases this distinction is, from the nature of the subject,
>   difficult to maintain, or entirely unappreciable.

Your example of "manic" and "maniacal" isn't quite parallel here.  Both adjectives derive from the word "mania," but the latter has goes through "maniac" and has a long history -- the *OED* finds a use in print from 1678 -- while the former was invented directly from "mania" in 1921 for use in psychiatry.  Nevertheless, as applied to smiles (or laughter), they mean the same thing.  Just the way "egotistic" and "egotistical" are little different.

Differences in the two forms do obtain.  A well-known example is "historic" (which means noteworthy) and historical (which means of narrative history).  But usage dictates the divergence, and there's no general rule to distinguish the difference between the two forms, if indeed one exists.

Comment: Why are you answering duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no defined difference between the words. They are simply different forms of the word.

*Maniac* is a **noun** while *maniacal* is an **adjective**. While *maniac* is a person, *maniacal* describes a behavior or attribute.

*Egotistic* and *egotistical* are both **adjectives** and can be used interchangeably. *Egotistic* is most common of course.

**[-ic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ic?s=t)**

> a noun suffix occurring chiefly in loanwords from Greek, where such
>   words were originally adjectival ( critic; magic; music).

**[-al](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-al?s=t)**

> a suffix with the general sense “of the kind of, pertaining to, having
>   the form or character of” that named by the stem, occurring in
>   loanwords

Comment: Note that the question mentions the adjective _manic_, not the noun _maniac_.